# Can't reach 127.0.0.1 but can reach localhost in MS Edge

Tags: http, microsoft-edge

On MS Edge:

I can access to `https://localhost`

I cannot access to `https://127.0.0.1`

On the others browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) it works

Comment: Solution provided by John can solve your issue. You can try to test it and let us know, whether it works for you or not. If it works than try to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer may help other community members in future in similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sorry @Deepak-MSFT I was on holidays :)

Comment: you not need to add any protocol. You can just type 127.0.0.1 in the address bar will show you the result.

Comment: I know but I want to work under https

Comment: I am not sure how did you configure the 127.0.0.1 with HTTPS. I made a test on my side with IIS and MS Edge. I try to configure it using self signed certificate and It is allowing me to acess 'https://'127.0.0.1' with warning message. See here.. https://i.postimg.cc/WzNY2NT2/1.png

Comment: Doesn't work for me: i.postimg.cc/R0wKdhDX/Capture18.png

Comment: You need to inform us your steps, how did you configure it. So we can check whether it is correct or not. only saying it is not working will not help us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I didn't change anything but the option John Hoang suggested, do you want to see any configurations?

Comment: I added the HTTPS binding for port 443 for localhost. I also added the SSL certificate in that binding. So I think you also need to configure like this to make it work. you can share your configuration. we will try to check it.

Answer (score 5):

MS Edge is a Windows Store app. So loopback access has been disabled for security purposes.

To enable, type:

```
about:flags
```

Look at **"Developer Settings"**, enable **"Allow Localhost Loopback"**

Comment: Hi John! Welcome and thanks for your answer! I'm giving you points for the answer but it isn't working on https. I don't know what's happening, I'm getting `Hmmm...can’t reach this page` message

Comment: The flag name was changed, I enabled "WebTransport Developer Mode" and 127.0.0.1:5000 worked after giving me an Access Denied